# How can I get all REST API Methods from website without public documentation

Tags: api, rest, routes

There is a website https://api.somewebsite.com/
I need to get api methods (routes) and queries to get data from them

Lets pretend they dont have any docs.
Is there a way to do it?

I tried to find some website to do that for me.
I didn't come with a better idea than bruteforce uri and look at the responses

Comment: Which website you are talking about it?

Comment: https://commonapi.ilcats.ru/
Why that matters?

Comment: I guess you looking for car information by VIN number. This API will help you. https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/Home

Comment: No thats not what the question was about I wanted to get all api methods.
Doesn't matter what kind of website it is.

Comment: No way to get GET API list without documentation. Just a couple from Chrome's DevTool's Network panel.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.